# Error message from cx_freeze

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I use Winpython 3.4.4 and installed cx_freeze 5.0.1 from the repository without issues. I also run to the process of building a Windows installer file (.msi). Everthing was fine and I could install the software in a new pc. However, when I run it the following message stops the process. It looks like some files are missing. Some are from the numpy module some others are obscure.

How can I get some guidelines ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: use `'packages':['numpy']`.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568770/cx-freeze-building-a-project-to-an-exe-file-getting-numpy-import-errors